# После перехода с http на https перестал работать fancybox

Tags: modx, https, fancybox

после того как перешел на https перестал работать fancybox https://bereza-ug.ru/kupe.html

в чем может быть причина? сайт на cms modx revo

Comment: Вероятно, вы подключали скрипты по http - сейчас браузеры по умолчанию блокируют загрузку http ресурсов с https страницы.

Answer (score 1):

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://bereza-ug.ru/dveri-iz-massiva-dereva.html' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Посмотрите в консоль и сразу же найдете ответ.

Вы подключаете скрипты по http, а необходимо подключать по https.
Для этого необходимо явно указать что скрипт подключается по https, для этого ссылка на скрипт должна начинаться с `https://` или просто `//`